# Fitting a Logistic Curve, obtain parameters for each record

Tags: r, logistic-regression, model-fitting, economics

I'm attempting to fit a simple logistic curve, 1 response ~ 1 predictor.

```
library("drc")
mL <- drm(percent_farm_tractor ~ year, data = final.df, fct = L.3(), 
type = "continuous")
summary(mL)
plot(mL)
coef(mL)
modelFit(mL)
```

I'm used to using logistic regression as a classification method and the use of these packages is pretty unknown to me. This model returns the summary and fit plot below:

Model Summary

[image: Model Summary]

Plot

[image: Model Plot]

I understand "b" to be the slope, "d" to be the ceiling, and "e" to be the inflection point. To give some context I am looking at number a tractors in each county on a given year and expect this to follow the S-curve. So I am looking for these 3 parameters but for each county in my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
library(drc)
```

Split the data frame into a list of data frames, one per county:

```
split_df <- split(final.df, final.df$county)
```

A function to fit the model to a data set and return the coefficients:

```
fitfun <- function(d) {
    mL <- drm(percent_farm_tractor ~ year, data = d, fct = L.3(), type = "continuous")
    return(coef(mL))
}
```

Apply the function to each chunk of the data:

```
lapply(split_df, fitfun)
```

Comment: The problem I encountered was due to my data. This did return the proper results I was looking for. Thanks!